# How to handle bounce mail in PMTA

Tags: php, email

I added the following code to recive bounce email to  bounce@mydomain.com,

```
$headers .= "Return-path: bounce<bounce@mydomain.com>".$newLine;
$headers .= "Errors-To: bounce<bounce@mydomain.com>". $newLine;
$headers .= "Reply-To: bounce<bounce@mydomain.com>". $newLine;
```

I am using [PMTA](http://www.port25.com/) as my SMTP server.But the bounce mail was not recieved to bounce@mydomain.com,it is returned to the from address.How to handle this?

Comment: Try 'Return-Path' instead of 'Return-path'

Comment: @davey I checked with Return-Path,But still same error

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a Return-Path header; that will always be added by any mail server that handles the email.